# Extract paths from string file using regex (Linux)

Tags: regex, bash, path

I have a cache file containing text and paths to Linux files.
I would like to extract these files using Linux regex, but I'm not sure how to do it.
Here is a sample of what the cache file looks like:

```
/usr/bin/mk_cmds (not prelinkable)
/usr/bin/gcov:
/lib/libc-2.5.so [0xfff88e55]
    /lib/ld-2.5.so [0x7e786fcc]
/usr/lib/rpm/rpmdeps:
    /usr/lib/librpmbuild-4.4.so [0xdb141354]
    /usr/lib/librpm-4.4.so [0x4d8c8840]
```

Now here is what I would like to extract:

```
/usr/bin/mk_cmds
/usr/bin/gcov
/lib/libc-2.5.so
/lib/ld-2.5.so
/usr/lib/rpm/rpmdeps
/usr/lib/librpmbuild-4.4.so
/usr/lib/librpm-4.4.so
```

I tried a few things but none of them work (using grep):

`^(.*/)?(?:$|(.+?)(?:(\.[^.]*$)|$))`

`'(\/.+?) '`

Do you have any idea how I could do it? I have tried a few things but nothing worked.
Thank you very much

Comment: I suggest you add more tags that are relative to your question, like `regex` as well as the way you use to extract them (`bash`, `python` etc..)

Comment: @Armion : What flags did you pass to _grep_? `grep` can handle 3 different kinds of regular expressions. For instance, the `+` you are using, would not work with grep's _basic_ regular expressions. See the options `-E` and `-P` in grep.

Comment: Do any of the file paths have spaces in them?

Comment: With the assumptions that your pathnames begin with a `/` character and don't contain a white space or `:` character: `grep -o '/[^[:space:]:]*' cachefile`

Answer (score 1):

with:

`sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*\(.\+\)[: ]/\1/p' cachefile.txt`

`sed -n`: Sed editor in no print mode

- `s/`: Search the regex:
- `^[[:space:]]*`: Search lines starting either with spaces or nothing
- `\(.\+\)`: Capture 1 or more characters.
- `[: ]`: Followed by a colon `:` or a space  .
- `/\1/p`: Print the Regex captured group 1.

Test and play with this Regex in regex101.com:

https://regex101.com/r/lFzvYq/2

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sed -n '/:$/{s/:$//;p}; /]$/{s/^ *\(.*\) \[0x[0-9a-f]*\]$/\1/;p}'
```

This assumes that there are only two kinds of required lines in the cache. The ones ending with `:` and the ones ending with `]`.